# What is the difference SSE and SSEUP in x86-64-psABI chapter 3.2.3?

Tags: parameter-passing, x86-64, abi

In x86-64-psABI(https://github.com/hjl-tools/x86-psABI/wiki/x86-64-psABI-1.0.pdf), chapter 3.2.3, it defines some classes corresponding to AMD64 register.

1)What is the difference between `SSE` and `SSEUP`? `SSEUP` said "The class consists of types that fit into a vector register and can be passed and returned in the upper bytes of it" What does "can be passed and returned in the upper bytes of it" means?

2)What is the difference between `X87 X87UP` and `COMPLEX_X87`? They both looked identical.

```
3.2.3 Parameter Passing

After the argument values have been computed, they are placed either in regis- ters or pushed on the stack. The way how values are passed is described in the following sections.

Definitions We first define a number of classes to classify arguments. The classes are corresponding to AMD64 register classes and defined as:
INTEGER This class consists of integral types that fit into one of the general purpose registers.

SSE The class consists of types that fit into a vector register.

SSEUP Theclassconsistsoftypesthatfitintoavectorregisterandcanbepassed
and returned in the upper bytes of it.

X87, X87UP These classes consists of types that will be returned via the x87 FPU.

COMPLEX_X87 This class consists of types that will be returned via the x87 FPU.

NO_CLASS This class is used as initializer in the algorithms. It will be used for padding and empty structures and unions.
MEMORY This class consists of types that will be passed and returned in memory via the stack.
```

Answer (score 1):

The SSE registers have been extended from 128 (`xmm`) to 256 (`ymm`) and 512 bits (`zmm`).

The ABI doesn't try to use them horizontally but vertically first: if you have two `__m128` they are not passed in a single `ymm` register but in two.
However types such as `__m256` or `__m512`, instead, are passed in a `ymm` or `zmm`.

The `SSUP` classification is there to model this, the lower 128 bits of a SSE register are the lower bytes.

I think it is also assumed that have 256 or 512 bits can only be used with CPUs that have 256 or 512 bit registers.
I don't think it is legal to pass the four 128 bit chunks of a `__m512` in three `xmm` registers (the first fully used and the other two only used in their upper part).
The wording "that fit into a vector register" seems to imply so.

Comment: So with that saying, if I have two ```__m128```, the lower 8 bytes in first  ```__m128``` will fit in one xmm register and the rest will fit in the same xmm register. Since the second ```__m128``` has two classes, one is ```SSE```, the other is ```SSEUP``` and the previous xmm register has been taken, so the second ```__m128``` has to use the next xmm register. Is that right?

Comment: By the way, if that CPU doesn't have ymm or zmm register, how does the ```__m256``` or ```__m512``` get passed? Will the compiler complain about this?

Comment: @Kevin_xie each `__m128` get its `xmm` register. If the CPU doesn't have `ymm` or `zmm` registers either you don't have `__m256/512` or they are passed as structs.