# C#: Strange SSE calling convention for Vector3 and Vector4 on x86-64

Tags: c#, assembly, x86-64, sse, calling-convention

While playing around with the `Vector#` classes from `System.Numerics`, I noticed some very strange code generation occurring specifically with `Vector3` and `Vector4`: [Godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/z/T7EGnTo8h).

When `float` or `Vector2` is used as an argument or return type, the value is passed directly in the lower 32/64 bits of an SSE register, as I would expect. However, when using `Vector3` or `Vector4`, it seems that the value is being split across two SSE registers, without storing more than 2 float components per register and using shuffles+moves to assemble/disassemble the components into/from a single register. (In the case of `Vector3`, it also left- and right-shifts the whole vector in order to zero out the unused component).

What's the reasoning behind this? The only thing I can think of is that whatever calling convention is being used only allows passing individual `float`/`double` values in SSE registers, and that this is being worked around by packing two `float`s as a "`double`". However, this doesn't seems to coincide with either the [Microsoft x64 convention](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/x64-calling-convention?view=msvc-170&viewFallbackFrom=vs-2017) (which passes single `float`s`/double`s in SSE registers, but requires that `__m128` values be passed as a pointer) or `__vectorcall` (which would allow the full `__m128` value to be passed in a register without requiring it to be broken up). [It would seem that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57852034/what-is-the-difference-sse-and-sseup-in-x86-64-psabi-chapter-3-2-3) the System V AMD64 ABI allows passing an `__m128` in a single SSE register. Is this some non-standard calling convention that C# uses internally, is it using the System V ABI and interpreting `Vector3`/`4` as a union rather than `__m128`, or what's going on here?

Comment: Wow, that Example3 with two Vector3 args is total garbage.  Even with just SSE2, it could introduce a zero and merge with `pslldq xmm1, 12` / `shufps xmm0, xmm1, _MM_SHUFFLE(0, 3, 1,0)`, instead of an extra `psrldq xmm1, 12` to shift it back to the bottom (and then still using `vshufpd` instead of `vmovlhps`).  With SSE4 or AVX2, it could merge and zero the top element with a single `[v]insertps`.  And it doesn't seem to realize that `vshufpd` has 3 vector operands plus an immediate, so it doesn't need a `vmovaps` first.

Comment: I wonder if using the bottom half of XMM regs is how Windows x64 passes aggregates, like structs or unions with FP members?  But no, probably not, the way MSVC defines `__m128` is as a union of structs (of arrays).   This choice is consistent with non-vectorcall limiting every arg-passing slot to 8 bytes so it can be dumped to shadow space, but one arg is taking 2 slots.  It does seem to be a different calling convention, which is fine; C# can't directly call C.  Even with a good implementation of it, maybe less efficient than just store/reload for some cases, so I'm not sure it's a good idea.

Comment: You're seeing extra quirks here because godbolt uses the Linux version of .NET (so largely based on SysV AMD64 instead of Win64). And `Vector4` is a struct, `Vector128` is the `__m128`-like type

Comment: @harold The generic `Vector###<T>` types are always passed on the stack, it doesn't appear to get any special handling - if anything, it's `Vector#` which is getting special treatment by the compiler.

Comment: @DaPorkchop_ it's not special, you can define your own struct with 4 floats and [the same thing happens](https://godbolt.org/z/7ErGjj5K4) (on Linux - none of this weirdness happens on Windows). `Vector###<T>` being passed on the stack is the weird one (whether it's desirable is a different question)